# Do while work in C++ but not in C# and i don't know why

Tags: c#

my do while function doesn't work in C# and i can't figure it out why, so here is the code :

I'm new to the community, the same code works well when is written is C++

Thanks !
[image]

```
    using System;






namespace MiniCalculator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double nb, nb1, result;
            string ope, go;
            

            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do ? Choose the operator between these propositions : + - * / ");
                ope = Console.ReadLine();

                if (ope != "+" && ope != "-" && ope != "*" && ope != "/")
                {
                    while (ope != "+" && ope != "-" && ope != "*" && ope != "/")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please, choose a right operator");
                        ope = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                else

                Console.WriteLine("Operator choosen : ", ope);
                Console.WriteLine("First number please.");
                nb = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Second number please.");
                nb1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (ope == "+")
                {
                    result = nb + nb1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is the result : " + result);
                }
                else if (ope == "-")
                {
                    result = nb - nb1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is the result : " + result);
                }
                else if (ope == "*")
                {
                    result = nb * nb1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is the result : " + result);
                }
                else if (ope == "/")
                {
                    result = nb / nb1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is the result : " + result);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to do another calculation ? (Y/n)");
                go = Console.ReadLine();

                if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            } while (go == "y" || go == "Y");
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no error description.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and describe the problem clearly. What happens when you try running the code? What is supposed to happen instead? How is that different? Then **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "why" or "how" and ending with a question mark (`?`). Please make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*; pleasantries like "I'm new to the community" are not useful for helpful, and "I can't figure out why" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: You need to debug your code and you need to do so BEFORE posting here. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through line by line, examining the state at each step. Then you will be able to see EXACTLY what it is doing and EXACTLY how that behaviour differs from your expectation. If you still can't work out what to do about it, at least you'll be able to provide us with all the relevant information rather than just "here's all my code, you tell me what's wrong".

Answer (score 3):

You code summarizes to

```
 do{

......

} while (go == "y" && go == "Y");
```

So this continues running when go == "y" and == "Y"

That can never happen, so it runs once

I think you mean

```
 while (go == "y" || go == "Y");
```

---

You seem to think there is something magic going on here

look at this code

```
        if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

We should consider 3 possibilities for go values

```
go = "X"
go = "Y"
go = "y"
```

which one of these will make your program exit

well with "X"

```
     if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
     ------true      ----true
```

So exit

with "Y"

```
     if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
     -------true     ---false
```

so exit

with "y"

```
      if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
      -------false     ----true
```

so exit

There is no combination that does not exit.

You had the same problem with your while but inverted, it was always false

and I 100% guarantee that this is the same in c++

Comment: I tried both and both not work, the console just stop.

In C++ i made this
if (go != "y" && go != "Y")
    {
        return 0;
    }

  }while(go == "y");

And this work. 

Comment: @StackImStuck well I ran it and the code works fine, please edit your question to show the code with || in it as I suggested

Comment: @StackImStuck - yes that c++ code works fine, because its not the same code as you show here. If you put this code in c++ it will fail the same

Comment: @StackImStuck I did not tell you to edit that line before Envoronment.Exit - just the while line. You just moved the bug from the while to the exit

Comment: Damn that's work, i don't know exactly why because this is the same operator so this should not be doing the same stuff ? ‍♂️

Comment: You should debug your code, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Debug like what ? I'm newbie and when i compile i don't have any error.

Comment: But you know how to use google? First link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: @StackImStuck - see edit

Comment: @StackImStuck - debugger is nothing to do with getting errors when you compile or run the program.  Nor is it an advanced thing for experienced devs. It takes 5 minutes to learn how to use the excellent debugger in VS.

Comment: I confused the two operators, stupid error sorry 
Thank's for the link i will read that, seem's very useful.

Comment: Maybe you should even start with this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp The explanation by pm100 is really good, but no explanation on Stackoverflow can be as good as debugging code and finding issues on your own. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code

```
if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
 {
    Environment.Exit(0);
 }
```

This means that if go was y end the do while loop and exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (go != "y" || go != "Y")
 {
    Environment.Exit(0);
 }
```

this condition always exit your program..
try this:

```
if (go == "x" || go == "X")
{
     Environment.Exit(0);
}
```